# redirect to error page if requested language in URL not configured

Tags: sitecore-api

we have multilingual (FR / EN ) website .the issue is if we test with others language in URL like www/mydomain.com/dE  empty site will disply  our requirement is to redirect  to error page in case if langue not configured  or content version is 0 .

Comment: You need to write a simple pipeline which will check your language iso code from url and if doesn't exist then it will redirect to error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add below code in your layout which will check if the context language is other then FR & EN and will redirect on the Error page.

```
@{
    string lang = Sitecore.Context.Language.ToString();
    if(!lang.Contains("en") && !lang.Contains(""fr))
    {
         Response.Redirect("Your error page URL");
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps.